# Disable auto-sizing UICollectionView based on label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistackview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm using **UICollectionView** with **UIStackView**. Inside UIStackView, there are several labels and images. I need layout of **2** columns in each row of UICollectionView. For cell sizing I'm using following method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let padding: CGFloat = 10
    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding

    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: 400)
}
```

But as result I see different cell's width. 1st cell or 5th cell in one row, layout ignored my width. How can i make 2 columns always?

Comment: Please verify that either this method is running or not by adding break point into it.

Comment: Yes, all file. Moreover if I adding simple UIVIew to UICollectionView all works fine.

Comment: So you have cells containing UIStackViews? Anyway I suspect you are returning values from the other UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods that lead to a cell taking more than half width including interitem spacing etc.

Comment: I found interesting thing. **1)** If I use one UILabel inside UICollectionView and pin this label from all sides to superview with constraints - UICollectionView stretches direct UILabel width ignoring UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method. **2)** If I use height and width autoresizing mask for UILabel without constraints - **all works fine**. UILabel stretches like UICollectionView. **3) **UICollectionView with custom UIView (complex layout with constraints) doest work in any cases.